# How to access Object parameters having spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose if a object has parameters `var data={"f name":"vishal"}` and i want to access parameter "f name" in javascript. I know that there should not be space in parameters of a object but if it has space in it then how can i read it.

Comment: Bracket notation: `data["f name"]`

Comment: You can answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces in attribute names are perfectly OK in JavaScript. You reference them by the

```
object["param name"]
```

syntax. Moreover, any UTF8 character, except for control characters, are valid in attribute names.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
data['f name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket notation:

```
data["f name"]
```